# RSpec/Gem development: Stubbing rails templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rspec

I'm currently working on a couple of different gems both of which mainly consist of rails view helpers.

My problem is that some of these helpers require rendered rails templates to test the output - but I am unsure of the best way to stub a template, without a rails application. I presume that I should be able to leverage rspec-rails in some capacity, but i've been having trouble getting that to work without a rails app present.

Am I approaching this the wrong way? What's the current best-practice to test rails-specific features (in particular - things that happen only in the view) during gem development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the excellent [enginex](https://github.com/josevalim/enginex) gem, which helps you in setting up a gem skeleton with an embedded rails application for testing. This way you can easily test any rails dependency inside that application. To generate rspec tests run it as follows (default is test-unit):

```
enginex -t rspec your-gem-name
```

What I did to incorporate this into my gem, was run this inside some test folder, and copied the necessary files over to my gem. As an example, you could check it out inside [my cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/tree/master/spec).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :)